# PHP number format drops zero when rounding

Tags: php, jquery, number-formatting

I'm using PHP's number_format to display floats to 2 decimal places.

When the number is something like 1.898 it gets rounded up to 1.9.

How do I get it to display that as 1.90?

Update:

I have a function that ends...

```
return number_formant($num, 2);
```

The php script that calls the function prints out the number to be used by Javascript.  When I do a var_dump on the number, it prints correctly with two decimal places. Looks like it's Javascript that's loosing the zero.

Here's the JS code that was causing the issue...

```
function show_level(level) {
...
if (level > 9999)
    level_label = (level / 1000).toPrecision(3) + 'k';
else if (level > 999)
    level_label = (level / 1000).toPrecision(2) + 'k';
else
    level_label = level;
```

I altered the last line to get it working how I wanted..

```
  level_label = level.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: But, that's what it prints. You're probably not writing out the string immediately afterwards. Reveal your code.

Comment: *"When the number is something like 1.898 it gets rounded up to 1.9"*. No, that's not true.

Comment: clearly using 1 for decimals not 2, default is 0 so output would be "2"

Comment: If you have to use it for currency you can also use: string money_format ( string $format , float $number ) http://it2.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: Can you post the relevant JS code now?  Thx.

Comment: @liz 5 people wasted their time with php answers when its a js question, you should spend as much time in asking as you hope others will spend in answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution but:

```
$n = 1.2345;
$n = number_format( round($n, 1), 2);
//echo 1.20
echo $n;
```

Comment: this will cause rounding/precision errors.  showing 2 decimal places when you're rounding to one is poor form.

Comment: That's what the question asked (in the first place) then edited.

Answer (score 1):

So,
you mean something like this (what you have):

```
<?php
echo number_format($x);
?>
```

and here is what you want:

```
<?php
echo number_format($x,2);
?>
```

you can use other lengths. Try it Out!

Hope could helpya
:)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo sprintf('%01.2f', number_format(1.898,2))
```

Comment: Psst: `sprintf` has the `%f`, too. ;)

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
echo round(1.898,2);
```